# Extract a single subfolder from a zip file on windows

Tags: zip, extract

I am new user . I want delete 1 folder from multiple ZIP file
Folder name is common i.e "HIL" .
and it is taking time to delete this folder manually so can we create batch file? Please guide

Comment: What zip software are you using and what have you tried? Extract or delete?

Comment: i am using 7 zip & winzip and i have to delete the file

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
7z d archive.7z -r dir/
```

This recursively removes a sub-folder named `dir` from the archive `archive.7z`.